# JMS Get message/response from EJB

Tags: java, ejb, jms

This is my sender class:

```
private void sendJMSMessage(Object data) throws JMSException {
        Connection con = null;
        Session s = null;
        try {
            con = context.createConnection();
            s = con.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = s.createProducer(glassFishQueue);
            ObjectMessage msg = s.createObjectMessage();
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list.add("name");
            msg.setObject(p);
            producer.send(msg);
        }
```

And my Message-driven Bean:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        ObjectMessage om = (ObjectMessage) message;
        ArrayList al = (ArrayList) om.getObject();
        System.out.println("Msg: " + al.get(0));

    } catch (JMSException jex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + jex);
    }
```

I got the message sent from sender class but I need a message back from EJB to the sender.
Im doing a web client with a table but I need to fill it getting the info from a database remotely, I really doesnt know what i should to use to do this, so if im doing right let me know or tell me any suggestion

Thank u

Comment: Does your EJB implement `javax.jms.MessageListener`?

Comment: Yeah, there is where i override onMessage()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JMS` is asynchronous, so it won't work in request-response style out of the box.

If you want to send a reply, one way is to use a separate queue. Your `MDB` can write the response to this second queue and your client can listen to this queue by creating a [`QueueReceiver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueReceiver.html).

Another way is to use [`QueueRequestor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueRequestor.html). From javadocs:

> It creates a TemporaryQueue for the responses and provides a request
>   method that sends the request message and waits for its reply.

Look [here](https://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/queueRequestor-1.htm) and [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/QueueRequestorExample) for `QueueRequestor` examples.